# Cannot set property 'color' of undefined getting this error in React

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am trying to change colour of text in h1 tag when I click button. I am calling change colour function but when onclick it executes at that time it is showing error in the inside statement **[ this.styling_text.color="black" ]**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class InlineDynamic extends Component{

     changeColor = () =>{
           this.styling_text.color="black"
           
    };

    
    render(){

      const styling_text = {color:"red"};
        
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 style={styling_text} >Change My Colour !! on click</h1>
              
                <button onClick={this.changeColor}>click me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InlineDynamic;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the color property, add styling_text object to the component state:

```
class InlineDynamic extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      styling_text: { color: "red" },
    };
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({ styling_text: { color: "black" } });
  };

  render() {
    const {styling_text} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={styling_text}>Change My Colour !! on click</h1>

        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Other solution is to use React.createRef :

```
class InlineDynamic extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
    super();
    this.styling_text = React.createRef(null);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.styling_text.current.style.color = "black";
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.styling_text.current.style.color = "red";
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 ref={this.styling_text}>Change My Colour !! on click</h1>

        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can we do without using setstate()

Comment: You can use createRef, I update my answer. I prefer the first solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare `styling_text`  outside of `render`

```
class InlineDynamic extends Component{

     changeColor = () =>{
           this.styling_text.color="black"
           
    };

    styling_text = {color:"red"};
    
    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <h1 style={styling_text} >Change My Colour !! on click</h1>
              
                <button onClick={this.changeColor}>click me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: it still giving error because style={styling_text} is class property hence we have to use style={this.styling_text}.But after using that also it throws same error.